# Spark Dataframe concatenate strings

Tags: scala, apache-spark

How to concatenate Date and Time column (both string) using Spark-Scala

```
+---+-------------------+-----+
| ID|   Date            |Time
+---+------------------ +-----+
|  G|2014.01.14 00:00:00| 1:00
+---+-------------------+------

"2014.01.14 1:00"
```

Comment: you can do `df.withColumn("newCol", concat_ws(" ", col("Date"), col("Time")))`

Comment: Yes, I knew this approach, but what I don't know is that how to remove "00:00:00" from Date Column

Comment: you can use regex_replace function for that

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this,

```
result.withColumn("Date && Time", concat(regexp_replace(col("date"),"00:00:00",""), lit(""), (col("time"))))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use :

```
result.withColumn("Date && Time", concat(col("Date"), lit(""), (col("Time")) ));
```